# Can we delete /storage/emulated/0/tencent/MicroMsg/03a...df5/sfs/avatar.block.00008?

Tags: internal-storage

What does this file do? It's part of wechat but is it just a cache of avatars? It's 256mb.

Comment: What's its extension?

Answer (score 4):

According to the info provided by [this thread on XDA](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2434400), any data contained within **tencent/MicroMsg** and its subdirectories, does not consist of chat backups and/or relevant data.

Instead, the folder tree contains several large cache files (for avatars and chats), and media files (pictures, music, video) sent to you by other users. This theory has been supported by the fact that, backing up the **tencent/MicroMsg** folders, uninstalling WeChat, reinstalling it, and then restoring the backed up tree, does not restore neither your previous chats, nor your old session.

Still, the app does never accomplish any maintenance on its cache, so that's a duty that must be carried out by the end user, while WeChat contacts and chats are stored within internal sql databases on the **/data** partition.

Answer (score 1):

Clear out your old messages and see if the file shrinks (assuming you are concerned with this because of the large amount of storage it is taking). If it does, it's the file that contains all of your messages. Otherwise, it could be a cache or data that was never deleted by the app when it was done with it.

If you want to get rid of it to save space, do the things I listed below. If you are merely concerned with what it is, it's probably the file that contains your messages.

**If you are concerned with saving space:** After deleting your old messages, if the file does not shrink, clear the app cache through settings-> apps->wechat->clear cache and see if the file disappears. If it doesn't, that is a data file for the app probably holding contacts and messages. Deleting and reinstalling the app will likely delete the file, but double check that your contacts are saved somewhere else before doing that.

I must note, randomly deleting files that are not part of a cache can cause the app to crash when it is restarted or destroy data that you do not want to delete.

Comment: We should also say that, often, messaging apps store their contacts and messages in their /data/data/name_of_the_package/databases. Are you sure that the mentioned file would be critical?

Comment: @DeathMaskSalesman If that file is all of the user's contacts and messages with no cloud backup, id definitely call that critical, but I see your point. Editing.

Comment: I was not suggesting an edit. Mine was mere speculation about the fact that no severe damage can be done by messing with internal/external SD files, as long as it doesn't involve the deletion of licenses.

Comment: @DeathMaskSalesman no severe damage, no, but extremely undesired behavior, yes.

Comment: It would be useful if we could analyze it.